# send bold text on telegram bot with java-netbeans

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I have my telegram bot working, but I want to make some modifications to the messages I am sending, such as sending text in bold, italics or strikethrough, I tried using the "code" in Unicode (because that way I send emojis like "\ uD83D \ uDEA8 "for the police siren emoji) for bold but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```java
String startBold = "\\033[1m";
String endBold = "\\033[0;0m";
String msg = "The" + startBold + " text" + endBold + " is bold.";

String json = "{\"chatId\":\"<<chatId>>\",\"key\":\"<<key>>\",\"botId\":\"<<botId>>\",\"msg\":\" " + msg + " \",\"username\":\"<<username>>\"}";


String url = "https://sendMessage.com/rest-messaging/service/bot/sendMessage";

StringEntity body = new StringEntity(json.toString());
String result = sendMessage.telegramNotifications(url, json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram allows you to use **Markdown** for text formatting.

You can make your text **bold** by surrounding it with `*`, for example: `*bold text*`

Note that you have to switch `parse_mode` to `Markdown` or `MarkdownV2` for this to work.

More info: [core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)